# 2D array Seven Segment Digital Clock implementation

Tags: c++

Hey all I am new to programming and this site in general..and maybe have bitten off more than i can chew with this...but I was wanting to learn about classes so I found a UML diagram that is about a digital clock with a seven segment display. I was able to discern what the UML diagram wanted as far as private functions and public and was able to get the separate class files constructed and now have the classes structured as a skeleton but have been at a loss as to how to continue. here are the files I have so far:
The base class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Declare and initialize a speed increase, or decrease
const int ROWS = 10;  // move this to base class


class ClockCharacter
{
private:
   //Field declarations

public:
   virtual string getRow(int aRow) = 0; // pure virtual function == abstract class

}; //end class
```

and the other classes to help piece together the clock:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class DigitalClock
{
    private:

        DigitalClockDisplay aDigitalClockDisplay;

    public:
        /**
        * Constructor. Empty.
        */
        DigitalClock()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Set the hours, minutes and seconds of the DigitalClockDisplay.
        */
        void setTime(int theHours, int theMinutes, int theSeconds)
        {

        }

        /**
        * Based on a 12 hour clock, get the current hour and increment it.
        * If the result exceeds 12 hours wrap back to the 1st hour.
        */
        void incrementHours()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Based on a 60 minute hour, get the current minute and increment it.
        * If the result exceeds 60 minutes wrap back to the 1st minute and increment the hour.
        */
        void incrementMinutes()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Based on a 60 second minute, get the current second and increment it.
        * If the result exceeds 60 seconds wrap back to the 1st second and incremnt the minute.
        */
        void incrementSeconds()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Based on a 12 hour clock, get the current hour and decremnt it.
        * If the result is less than the 1st hour, wrap back to the 12th hour.
        */
        void decrementHours()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Based on a 60 minute hour, get the current minute and decrement it.
        * If the result is less than 1 minutes, wrap back to the 59th minute and decrement the hour.
        */
        void decrementMinutes()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Based on a 60 second minute, get the current second and decrement it.
        * If the result is less than 1 second wrap back to the 59th second and decremnt the minute.
        */
        void decrementSeconds()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Request that the DigitalClockDisplay display its time.
        */
        void displayTime()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Increment the seconds after a one second delay.
        */
        void run()
        {

        }

}; // End class

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class DigitalClockDisplay : public DigitalClock
{
    private:
        SevenSegment hTensDigit;
        SevenSegment hOnesDigit;
        SevenSegment mTensDigit;
        SevenSegment mOnesDigit;
        SevenSegment sTensDigit;
        SevenSegment sOnesDigit;
        Colon aColon;
        DigitalClock aDigitalClockDisplay;

    public:
        /**
        * Constructor to initialize the instance.
        */
        DigitalClockDisplay()
        {

        }

        /**
        * The specified value is separated into its two digit components.
        * The tens position is sent to the SevenSegment representing the tens position
        *   and likewise for the ones position.
        */
        void setHours(int theTime)
        {

        }

        /**
        * The tens and ones digits are collected from the represective SevenSegments, combined and returned to caller.
        */
        int getHours()
        {
            return Hours;
        }

        /**
        * The specified value is separated into its two digit components.
        * The tens position is sent to the SevenSegment representing the tens position
        *   and likewise for the ones position.
        */
        void setMinutes(int theTime)
        {

        }

        /**
        * The tens and ones digits are collected from the represective SevenSegments, combined and returned to caller.
        */
        int getMinutes()
        {
            return Minutes;
        }

        /**
        * The specified value is separated into its two digit components.
        * The tens position is sent to the SevenSegment representing the tens position
        *   and likewise for the ones position.
        */
        void setSeconds(int theTime)
        {

        }

        /**
        * The tens and ones digits are collected from the represective SevenSegments, combined and returned to caller.
        */
        int getSeconds()
        {
            return Seconds;
        }

        /**
        * Output is generated one line at a time by calling getRow() for each of the display components.
        */
        void DisplayTime()
        {
            getRow()
        }

        /**
        * Each of the SevenSegment components is initialized to zero (0).
        */
        void initialize()
        {
            hTensDigit = 0;
            hOnesDigit = 0;
            mTensDigit = 0;
            mOnesDigit = 0;
            sTensDigit = 0;
            sOnesDigit = 0;
        }
}; // End Class

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Colon : public ClockCharacter
{
    private:
        int static const COLUMNS = 7;
        string digitArray[ROWS + 1][COLUMNS + 1];

        DigitalClockDisplay aColon;

    public:
        /**
        * Constructor to initialize the instance.
        */
        Colon()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Set the appropriate segments in the digitArray[][].
        */
        void setColon()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Remove values that were set in setColon();
        */
        void clearColon()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Returns a string of all the cells values for the specified row in digitArray[][].
        */
        string getRow(int aRow)
        {

        }

        /**
        * Clear the array representation by setting all cells to a space (" ").
        */
        void initialize()
        {
            string digitArray[ROWS + 1][COLUMNS + 1] = {{" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                        {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}};
        }
}; // End class

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SevenSegment : public ClockCharacter
{
    private:
        int static const COLUMNS = 7; // Defines the number of columns for the SevenSegment array representation.

        /**
        * This is the array representation of the SevenSegment display. 
        * It is declared with one more row and column to account for the 0 element.
        */
        string digitArray[ROWS + 1][COLUMNS + 1]; 

        int digitValue; // this variable stores the value that the SevenSegment represents. It can be used for calculations.

        DigitalClockDisplay hTensDigit;
        DigitalClockDisplay hOnesDigit;
        DigitalClockDisplay mTensDigit;
        DigitalClockDisplay mOnesDigit;
        DigitalClockDisplay sTensDigit;
        DigitalClockDisplay sOnesDigit;

    public:
        /**
        * Constructor to initialize the instance.
        */
        SevenSegment()
        {

        }

        /**
        * Set the digitValue and set the appropriate segments in the digitArray[][]. 
        * Each of the seven segments will be either set or cleared depending on the specified digit.
        */
        void setDigit(int aValue)
        {

        }

        /**
        * Return the digitValue.
        */
        int getDigitValue()
        {
            return digitValue;
        }

        /**
        * Sets the specified segment.
        */
        void setSegment(int aSegment)
        {
            Segment = aSegment;
        }

        /**
        * Clears the specified segment.
        */
        void clearSegment(int aSegment)
        {

        }

        /**
        * Returns a string of all the cells values for the specified row in digitArray[][].
        */
        string getRow(int aRow)
        {
            return Row;
        }

        /**
        * Clear the array representation by setting all cells to a space (" ").
        */
        void initialize()
        {
             string digitArray[ROWS + 1][COLUMNS + 1] = {{" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}, 
                                                         {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "}};
        }
}; // End class
```

I am picking apart the comments left by the UML diagram and I think I have a couple of them correct.. but I am still struggling with the rest. I have only the books I was recommended by other programmer friends and since I am so new some of the material is a little beyond me. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. I was looking up the Seven Segment display and was thinking I could design the numbers kind of like how I set up the `void initialize()` function but instead of spaces I could use the `*` symbol? again any help is greeted with a welcome arm and gratitude returned.

Comment: This isn't a question. Write a short piece of code at the attempt of what you're trying, and then write a **specific** question. Without both you won't get answers.

Comment: note the question mark at the end of "I could use the `*` symbol" signifying that indeed I was asking that question. and I HAVE included code that I wrote. If you read it I was asking if I could make the numbers structured in the same fashion that I did the spaces.

Comment: The code you provided is generally incomplete and immaterial to the question you seem to be asking...the '*' operator can do a lot of things so the answer to your "question" is probably yes.  Provide some specific code and reference your question to that.